# Binding a Backbone.js object to a Spring Controller while utilising @InitBinder

Tags: spring-mvc, backbone.js

I am having trouble getting @InitBinder to work with Backbone.js

```
@InitBinder
public final void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    // Customer property editors
    binder.registerCustomEditor(MyObjectChild.class, new MyObjectChildEditor());
}
```

I have a controller like this that accepts the object

```
@RequestMapping(
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
public final String create(@RequestBody final MyObject myobject) {

    return "worked";
}
```

MyObject has a property of type MyObjectChild.  I would like to pass the ID values of this object from the frontend to the controller because it does not make sense for the user to have the ability to modify it (they will select it from the drop down list).

I have read that @RequestBody does not work with @InitBinder so I tried @ModelAttribute instead, but I don't know what the @ModelAttribute name would be because it is created on the frontend in javascript using Backbone.js.

How do I get Backbone.js to work with Spring @InitBinder?

Comment: `PropertyEditors` aren't used when sending/receiving JSON only for form based solution (or non-json). For JSON marshalling/unmarshalling Spring used Jackson, you would need to create a plugin/converter for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921089/jackson-converting-json-property-to-nested-object-with-dot-notation has a nice overview of the different solutions.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll look into the jackson way of doing it.